# Databricks Job fails with exception: UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the CredentialScopeFileSystem FileSystem implementation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake, aws-databricks

Some of my jobs are failing since I enabled Unity Catalog on a workspace with the following error:

```
UnsupportedOperationException: Not implemented by the CredentialScopeFileSystem FileSystem implementation
```

This is happening when I am trying to call `delta_table.vacuum()`.

The cluster that I am using, was being updated by dbx in a CI/CD pipeline. If you don't specify the new property `data_security_mode`, the cluster automatically gets the access mode `SINGLE_USER`.

The job stops failing when I use the **No Isolation Shared** option, which unfortunately disables Unity Catalog on that cluster.

Comment: Could you raise a ticket to Databricks instead? This is a bug that cannot be solved here.

Comment: I unfortunately can not, since I don't have access to support.